# How to check if dictionary is empty and dictionary is like {"":""} in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I am working on AWS_SECRETS and want to check whether secrets values(KEY/VALUE pair) has been created or not for this i am using boto3 script which is returning an empty dictionary like below

```
{"":""}
```

Since there is no value it is being consider as a string. Please let me know how to iterate over this.

objective is to return "empty dict" in case of `{"":""}` and if its like `{"Key":"Value"}` then it should return that dictionary is not empty.

or if anyone has a better suggestion/(s) then please suggest.

Note: Terraform is being used to create `AWS_SECRET`, so `AWS_SECRET` will be created by terraform only but if I need to check whether it has some values or no that i am handing using `boto3`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `dict.keys()` to get all the keys. You can then compare this to a tuple with just `""` in it.

```
if tuple(d.keys()) == ("",):
    print("dict is empty")
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `any(d.keys()) or any(d.values())`:

```
>>> d = {"": ""}
>>> any(d.keys()) or any(d.values())
False

>>> d = {"foo": ""}
>>> any(d.keys()) or any(d.values())
True

>>> d = {"foo": "bar"}
>>> any(d.keys()) or any(d.values())
True
```

Note that this assumes that keys and values are always strings. It would fail with other falsy values, for example:

```
>>> d = {False: False}
>>> any(d.keys()) or any(d.values())
False
```